# Invalid Date Error while sending a csv through Email Service

Tags: apex-email-service

I am getting an error of invalid date when I am sending a csv through an email service. Here is the snippet of my code.

```
if (csvAsStringRowElement.size() > 0 && csvAsStringRowElement[4] != null && csvAsStringRowElement[4].trim().length() > 0) {

Date dat = Date.parse(csvAsStringRowElement[4]);
system.debug('dat-->'+dat);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the datetime to the following format:-

2017-01-01T23:01:01Z

Also refer to the following link for more on date formats :-
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm

Comment: It's a normal date field and the document you have referred does not exist

Comment: @manchesterunited Can u plz check once again the URL and compare the format . Also just to confirm try to enter the same date in the same format manually using workbench.